# Finding confidence level of miRNA disease associations

Tags: bioinformatics, pathology, rna, genomics

I'm an undergraduate computer engineering student, and I have a project about bioinformatics. In this manner, I need to find prediction( or association I'm not sure the correct terminology) confidence of miRNA disease relationships. Let me make more clear my question with an example. For instance, in one of the bioinformatics related databases( HMDD) it is said that, miRNA X is related with disease Y. I want to find that what is the confidence. I mean  you're 100% sure about such releationship? Do you know any database for that purpose? In HMDD I can only find miRNA - disease name couples it does not give any statistics.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular database, but isn't there any reference for such entry?

Comment: @poka.nandor Actually neither I am, after I asked this question, I looked at HMDD again and I saw that in the explanation of hmdd, it is said that "HMDD  is a database that curated experiment-supported evidence for human microRNA (miRNA) and disease associations." so, since it is curated experiment-supported I think they're 100% sure about their associations

Comment: I haven't come across with a reliable database. For the one that you are talking about, if they haven't provided any association 'scores' then you can download the entire data and calculate them yourself. Read the paper/additional data corresponding to the database; they must have done normalization and must have calculated some scores

Answer (score 1):

You can start off by studying how an miRNA regulates the functioning of a gene. it basically binds to the 3'UTR and 5'UTR of an mRNA and restricts its translation. There will be genes associated with the disease of your interest,  find out the miRNA's related to those genes. You can use micro array data to find out the up-regulated genes. Target scan human, miRDB, are various databases for retrieving the miRNA's related with the genes. 
The confidence level for finding out the association of certain miRNA's with the disease can never be 100%. but a relationship can be established by simply viewing the complementarity between the miRNA and the mRNA expressed during the diseased state.

Comment: Could you add links or citations for people to read further into this topic?